# merge 2 tables and keeping duplicates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table

I need your help on the following question:
I have 2 data tables:

DF1:

```
Country Y   Freq
FRANCE  1    0
FRANCE  1    1
ITALY   1    2
ITALY   1    3
SPAIN   1    4
```

DF2:

```
Country Z    T
FRANCE  1    0
FRANCE  1    1
ITALY   1    2
SPAIN   2    3
SPAIN   1    4
```

I would like to obtain in my final table all possible combinations between DF1 and DF2:
each row in DF1 should be duplicated n times its frequency in the DF2

```
DF final:
Country Y   Freq Z   T
FRANCE  1    0   1   0
FRANCE  1    0   1   1
FRANCE  1    1   1   0
FRANCE  1    1   1   1
ITALY   1    2   1   2
ITALY   1    3   1   2
SPAIN   1    4   2   3
SPAIN   1    4   1   4
```

Hope its clear,
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, all = T)`

Comment: Not really what I am looking for

Comment: @Rami Sma then please update your expected outcome as Maël's answer gives exactly what you added as "DF final"